# How can I sum and concentrate converted rows into one field with same id?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I am currently stuck with concat the two rows with same vm id
My origin sql data looks like this
[vm_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9MMc.png)
[vm_disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v17cM.png)

I have converted "datastores" from column to rows
This is my sql query,

```
SELECT vm.vm_info.id, 
    vm.vm_info.vm,
    vm.vm_info.vm_folder, 
  vm.vm_info.name, 
   vm.vm_info.cpu_count, 
    format(vm.vm_info.memory_size_MiB/1024,0) AS Memory_size_GiB, 
   vm_disk_convert.capacity,
    vm_disk_convert.NAS,
    vm_disk_convert.vSan,
    vm_disk_convert.vSan_intra,
    vm.vm_info.power_state, 
    vm.vm_info.modify_date
FROM vm.vm_info, (
    SELECT `vm`, `capacity`,
    case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "NFS-SA3400" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END AS NAS,
        case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "vsanDatastore" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END as vSan,
        case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "vsanDatastore-Intra" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END as vSan_Intra 
    FROM vm.vm_disk
) AS vm_disk_convert
WHERE vm.vm_info.vm = vm_disk_convert.vm
ORDER BY vm.vm_info.vm_folder, vm.vm_info.vm;
```

My current sql result looks like this
[sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJyRf.png)
I have tried with group_concat but result shows like this

How can I concentrate the rows with same vm id into one field?
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp5ZO.png)
Appreciate for helping me out!

Comment: Where are your ID's coming from?  
Your shifting them in your actual > Expected, so not sure what they're supposed to represent?  You've also got different capacities between the fields that your taking the Max of instead of summing.  Need a bit more info on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to sum the capacity in different datastores(hdd and ssd are seperated in different storage) which is the same vm id, and these vm ids are auto generated incrementally by vcenter. The one I'm trying to achieve is concating  the different datastores into one row  and sum the capacity in same vm id so they won't show ram and cpu resources twice with same vm id. Like the link below 
[result](https://imgur.com/a/xoWc3hc)

Comment: Simplify the problem, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: vm-822 has 2 different values for capacity in your actual results but you drop the 80 when you merge the tables in expected is primarily what I was talking about

Answer (score -1):

you can use GROUP BY Statement, it will be like this:

```
    SELECT vm.vm_info.id, 
    vm.vm_info.vm,
    vm.vm_info.vm_folder, 
  vm.vm_info.name, 
   vm.vm_info.cpu_count, 
    format(vm.vm_info.memory_size_MiB/1024,0) AS Memory_size_GiB, 
   vm_disk_convert.capacity,
    vm_disk_convert.NAS,
    vm_disk_convert.vSan,
    vm_disk_convert.vSan_intra,
    vm.vm_info.power_state, 
    vm.vm_info.os, 
    vm.vm_info.modify_date
FROM vm.vm_info, (
    SELECT `vm`, `capacity`,
    case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "NFS-SA3400" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END AS NAS,
        case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "vsanDatastore" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END as vSan,
        case when vm.vm_disk.datastores = "vsanDatastore-Intra" then vm.vm_disk.datastores END as vSan_Intra 
    FROM vm.vm_disk
) AS vm_disk_convert
GROUP BY `vm`
ORDER BY vm.vm_info.vm_folder, vm.vm_info.vm;
```

This statement do exactly what you want... if i wrote this wrong, i'm sorry, i'll give you the link to a tutorial that you can use in your project: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp